# "No routes matched location" error using react-router-dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

My App component without the imports:

```
function App() {
  const { token, login, logout, userId, userEmail } = useAuth();

  let routes;

  if (token) {
    routes = (
      <>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='profile' element={<Profile />} />
        <Route path='organizations' element={<Organizations />} />
        <Route path='organizations/events' element={<EventsCollection />} />
        <Route path='event/:eventId' element={<Event />} />
        <Route path='event/:eventId/order' element={<Order />} />
        <Route path='dashboard/:eventId' element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path='dashboard/:eventId/budget' element={<Budget />} />
        <Route path='dashboard/:eventId/contacts' element={<Contacts />} />
        <Route path='dashboard/:eventId/orders' element={<Orders />} />
        <Route path='dashboard/:eventId/tasks' element={<Tasks />} />
        <Route
          path='dashboard/:eventId/organization'
          element={<OrganizationDetails />}
        />
        <Route path='dashboard/:eventId/team' element={<Team />} />
        <Route path='dashboard/:eventId/event' element={<EventDetails />} />
        {/* <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to='/' replace />} /> */}
      </>
    );
  } else {
    routes = (
      <>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='login' element={<Login />} />
        <Route path='register' element={<Register />} />
        <Route path='event/:eventId' element={<Event />} />
        <Route path='event/:eventId/order' element={<Order />} />
        {/* <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to='/login' replace />} /> */}
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={lightTheme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{
          isLoggedIn: !!token,
          token: token,
          login: login,
          logout: logout,
          userId: userId,
          userEmail: userEmail,
        }}
      >
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>{routes}</Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

on `"/profile"` and `"/organizations"` I get a warning: "No routes matched location `"/profile"`" the page still loads and works fine but if I add `<Route path='*' element={<Navigate to='/' replace />} />` at the end of the routes and refresh the `Profile` page or the `Organizations` page I will be redirected for whatever reason. I cannot find the answer.

I tried nesting the routes but I cannot get it to work and I reorganized the paths but it still doesn't work like it is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on authentication status you are potentially not rendering some routes that you are trying to navigate to, e.g. `"/profile"`, `"/organizations*"`, and `"/dashboard*"` routes while a user is ***not*** authenticated. When you tried fixing this warning by rendering "catch-all" routes that redirect, the issue is now the user is being redirected prior to the authentication status "settling" to a known "state" of "authenticated" or "unauthenticated".

My suggestion is to ***not*** conditionally render routes such that they are ***always*** rendered and reachable, and to conditionally allow access to protected route content via a protected layout route component.

Create a `ProtectedRoutes` component that checks if a user is authenticated and conditionally render an `Outlet` component if they are, otherwise render a redirect to the login endpoint. I'm making the assumption that the initial `token` state value is undefined and is later updated to a defined value, e.g. `null` or a string value.

```
import { Outlet, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const { token } = useAuth();

  if (token === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return token
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};
```

Similarly create an `AnonymousRoutes` component that does the inverse of the `ProtectedRoutes` component. This will be used to protect routes you don't want authenticated users to be able to access, e.g. a login/registration route.

```
import { Outlet, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const AnonymousRoutes = () => {
  const { token } = useAuth();

  if (token === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return token
    ? <Navigate to="/" replace />
    : <Outlet />;
};
```

Next, merge all the routes you are rendering into a single configuration, using the appropriate route protection layout route components.

```
function App() {
  const { token, ...rest } = useAuth();

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={lightTheme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{
          isLoggedIn: !!token,
          token,
          ...rest
        }}
      >
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/event/:eventId">
              <Route index element={<Event />} />
              <Route path="order" element={<Order />} />
            </Route>
            <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to='/' replace />} />

            <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
              <Route path="profile" element={<Profile />} />
              <Route path="organizations">
                <Route index element={<Organizations />} />
                <Route path="events' element={<EventsCollection />} />
              </Route>
              <Route path="dashboard/:eventId">
                <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
                <Route path="budget" element={<Budget />} />
                <Route path="contacts" element={<Contacts />} />
                <Route path="orders" element={<Orders />} />
                <Route path="tasks" element={<Tasks />} />
                <Route path="organization" element={<OrganizationDetails />} />
                <Route path="team" element={<Team />} />
                <Route path="event" element={<EventDetails />} />
              </Route>
            </Route>

            <Route element={<AnonymousRoutes />}>
              <Route path='login' element={<Login />} />
              <Route path='register' element={<Register />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```